# Velleman's How to prove it. Partial order proof.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-verification

Theorem: Suppose that $R$ is a partial order on $A$, $B_1 ⊆ A$, $B_2 ⊆ A$, $x_1$ is the least
upper bound of $B_1$, and $x_2$ is the least upper bound of $B_2$. Prove that if
$B_1 ⊆ B_2$ then $x_1Rx_2$.

Analysis:

The goal is to prove $(x_1,x_2)\in R$. This means $x_2$ is LARGER than $x_1$.

The givens are:

1) $R$ is a partial order on $A$, $B_1 ⊆ A$, $B_2 ⊆ A$

2)$x_1$ is the least upper bound of $B_1$($x_1$ is an upper bound of $B_1$ AND $x_1$ is the smallest element of $U_1$). Translated to logic symbols mean: $\forall b_1 \in B_1[(b_1,x_1)\in R]$ $\land$ $\forall a\in U_1[(x_1,a)\in R]$. Where $U_1$ is the set of all upper bounds of $B_1$.

3)$x_2$ is the least upper bound of $B_2$. Translated to logic symbols mean: $\forall b_2 \in B_2[(b_2,x_2)\in R]$ $\land$ $\forall c\in U_2[(x_2,c)\in R]$. Where $U_2$ is the set of all upper bounds of $B_2$.

4)$B_1 \subseteq B_2$

5)Obviously $x_1\in U_1 \land x_2 \in U_2$.Both are also $\in A$.

Am stuck at this point. I tried contrapositive, direct, contradiction but to no avail. I tried cases like $x_1=x_2 \lor x_1\neq x_2$ but to no avail.

Some person wrote this proof:

Suppose $B_1 \subseteq B_2$. Let $b_1$ be arbitrary element of $B_1$, then $(b_1 R x_1)$. It follows from our assumption that $b_1 \in B_2$. So $(b_1 R x_2)$, hence $x_2$ is also an upper bound of $B_1$. Since $x_1$ is least upper bound of $B_1$, so it is smaller than any other upper bound of $B_1$, hence $(x_1 R x_2)$.

But I think it is wrong since the step "Let $b_1$ be arbitrary element of $B_1$" is unjustified(The only way to justify it is to have an existential quantifier[like $B_1$ is not a null set] in the givens which we don't have. Also the last part of it isn't justified(it assumes $x_1\in B_2$). Am I right ?

Can someone lend a hand here ? It would be great if you just gave a hint then write the answer in a hidden box.

Comment: @MarnixKlooster I put it in because of the proof that was given by "someone".

Comment: You have to prove that $x_2$, the l.u.b of $B_2$ is also an *upper boud* for $B_1$.

Comment: @Mauroallegranza Which I think pretty much means "The goal is to prove (x 1 ,x 2 )∈R . This means $x_2$   is LARGER than $x_1$  ." Isn't that right ?

Comment: It amounts to proving that $∀b_1 ∈ B_1 [(b_1,x_2) ∈ R]$. In this way, if $x_2$ is an *upper bound* for $B_1$, being $x_1$ the l.u.b. for $B_1$ : YES, we have that $x_2$ is LARGER that $x_1$.

Comment: @MAUROALLEGRANZA When we prove ∀$b_1$ ∈$B_1$ [($b_1$ ,$x_2$ )∈R]. We can put it in our "givens" list. But to use it $x_1$ must be in $B_1$ which may not be the case since it is not stated anywhere $x_1 \in B_1$

Comment: You have written "$x_1$ is the l.u.b. of $B_1$ iff $∀b_1 \in B_1[(b_1,x_1) ∈ R] \land ...$. Thus, to prove that $x_2$ is **an** u.b. of $B_1$ we have to prove that $∀b_1 \in B_1[(b_1,x_2) ∈ R]$. **But** $B_1 \subseteq B_2$; thus $∀b_1 \in B_1$, also $b_1 \in B_2$. We have that $x_2$ is the l.u.b. of $B_2$, so that $(b_1,x_2) \in R$.

Comment: @MauroAllegranza Yes, but AFTER you prove ∀$b_1$ ∈$B_1$ [($b_1$ ,$x_2$ )∈R. You still didn't prove $(x_1,x_2)\in R$. To use the statement $x_2$ is an u.b. of $B_1$ with $x_1$ you must show $x_1\in B_1$. Which is not given anywhere(right?).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with "some person's" proof which you quoted.

Comment: @bof The assumption that $x_1\in B_1 $ is not justified.

Comment: @MauroAllegranza Got you now. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: **NO**. For an $x$ to be an *upper bound* of a set $B$ is **not**  necessary that $x \in B$. Let $B = \{ 1,2,3 \}$, then $4,5,6$ are all upper bounds of $B$, because they all belong to the set $\mathbb N$ wich includes $B$ and is ordered by $\le$. In this case, of course $3$ is the l.u.b.; but if we use $<$ in place of $\le$, we have that it is nor more true that $\forall x \in B(x < 3)$. In this case, the l.u.b of $b$ is $4$.